# C++ Memory Leak Using char *

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

I'm writing a program to talk to a USB LCD display (Storm 5100-0103) and so far everything works fine, except that I have a memory leak somewhere.

```
mainLoop: while (true) {
    // Get the line
    std::getline(std::cin,stringIn);

    if (stringIn.find("~") == string::npos || stringIn.empty())
    {
        continue;
    }

    // split string to get line data and line number
    string data;
    int lineNo;

    // get the data portion
    data = stringIn.substr(0,stringIn.find("~"));

    // create a string for line number
    string lineNoString = stringIn.substr(stringIn.find("~") + 1, stringIn.length());

    // get line number
    lineNo = atoi(lineNoString.c_str());

    // Create a char array to pass to the displaya
    char *cstr = new char[data.size() + 1];
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), cstr);
    cstr[data.size()] = '\0';

    // Write line to the display
    retval = usbDisplayPtr->DrawString(0, lineNo,  1, cstr, USBDisplayApi::FONT6X16, 3000);

    cout << retval + "\n";

    delete[] cstr;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried valgrind?

Comment: seems like it should be delete cstr; instead of delete[] to me

Comment: @Steve `delete[]` is exactly what should be used when using `new[]`.

Comment: Rather than using new/delete use `std::vector` or `std::string` then you don't have to worry about releasing the memory yourself. The code you posted should only leak if an exception occurs between `new` and `delete`. The problem is in other code.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious if I remember right ....our prof memtioned something about the package containing vector might have some mem leak issue internally. So they are turning off mem leak detection when we are allowed to use that package

Comment: @Steve Either you misunderstood or your professor is wrong. Hopefully it's not the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You have your

```
char *cstr = new char[data.size() + 1];
```

and the corresponding

```
delete[] cstr;
```

and these are implemented correctly (matching `new[]` with `delete[]`).
Nowhere else in your code do you allocate memory on the heap, and I don't see anywhere that cstr is modified either.

All of these suggest that you *don't* have a memory leak, or at least, not in the code you have submitted here.

If you *think* you have a memory leak, you should confirm it.  Check the output from Valgrind (or a suitable alternative).